# Методы минимизации функции нескольких переменных

Tags: python, c++, оптимизация, r

Какой метод поиска минимума функции лучше всего использовать для такой задачи:
Есть функции двух, трёх переменных и нужно найти минимальное значение каждой из этих функций. Переменные лежат в пределах от 0.0001 до 0.9999 с шагом 0.0001. Если возможно, то с примерами кода на Python, R, C++. Пробовал связку: золотое сечение + покоординатный спуск - даёт непонятное отклонение в несколько десятых, сотых от нужного результата.

Comment: Приведите ваш код, может в коде проблема. Опять же смотря что за функции ещё.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

Comment: @CrazyElf вот моя тема с проблемой: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1203435/Неточность-в-нахождении-минимума-функции-в-r

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов встроенные методы оптимизации меня в данном случае не интересуют, спасибо!